# Count the amount of observations in predetermined timestep

Tags: r, date, time

I have a large dataset of over 75.000 observations. Of these observations I have a list of date and time combinations. I want to calculate the observation frequency in a predetermined timestep (15, 30 or 60 minutes). The study period is from 2014-10-21 00:00 to 2015-10-21 23:59.

The raw data is stored in a DF, but date (as POSIXlt) and time (as character) are in different columns, so I combine them back into one column to create a POSIXct timestamp.

```
receiver$date2 = as.POSIXct(paste(receiver$date, receiver$time), format="%Y-
%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dateseq = receiver$date2
```

dateseq is now (only a small fragment using dput()):

```
dateseq = structure(c(1414140420, 1414140720, 1414140960, 1414141080, 1414143540, 1414144980, 1414145940, 1414147380, 1414147440, 1414148100, 1414148280, 1414152720, 1414153740, 1414154520, 1414154580, 1414158540, 1414159380, 1414159680, 1414164240, 1414164300, 1414164840, 1414164900, 1414165500, 1414166100, 1414166220, 1414166460, 1414166520, 1414166820, 1414166880, 1414166940, 1414167300, 1414167360, 1414167480, 1414167780, 1414168380, 1414168440, 1414168800, 1414168860, 1414202040, 1414202220, 1414202280, 1414202700, 1414202820, 1414202880, 1414203660, 1414203960, 1414215180, 1414215300, 1414215900, 1414216560, 1414216860, 1414217220, 1414217280, 1414217460, 1414217580, 1414217700, 1414217820, 1414217880, 1414218240, 1414218720, 1414219380, 1414219800, 1414219920, 1414219980, 1414220160, 1414220280, 1414220820, 1414220880, 1414221000, 1414221960, 1414222080, 1414222200, 1414222320, 1414222500, 1414222560, 1414222860, 1414223640, 1414224780, 1414225800, 1414225920, 1414225980, 1414226040, 1414226100, 1414226220, 1414227240, 1414227420, 1414227600, 1414230300, 1414230540, 1414230840, 1414231140, 1414231320, 1414231440, 1414231560, 1414231800, 1414231860, 1414232040, 1414232160, 1414232400, 1414232520, 1414232640, 1414232700, 1414232760, 1414232880, 1414232940, 1414233060, 1414233180, 1414233240, 1414233300, 1414233420, 1414233480, 1414233660, 1414233720, 1414233780, 1414233840, 1414233960, 1414234080, 1414234320, 1414234440, 1414234560, 1414234620, 1414234740, 1414234860, 1414234980, 1414235040, 1414235280, 1414236240, 1414236300, 1414236420, 1414236540, 1414236840, 1414236900, 1414236960, 1414237020, 1414237260, 1414237560, 1414237860, 1414238280, 1414238400, 1414238460, 1414238580, 1414238640, 1414239180, 1414239300, 1414239360, 1414239480, 1414239540, 1414240440, 1414240860, 1414240920, 1414240980, 1414241040, 1414242000, 1414242180, 1414242480, 1414242540, 1414242660, 1414242720, 1414242840, 1414242900, 1414243800, 1414243920, 1414244280, 1414244460, 1414245240, 1414245600, 1414245660, 1414246080, 1414246500, 1414246680, 1414246740, 1414246920, 1414247340, 1414248180, 1414249320, 1414249560, 1414249860, 1414250340, 1414250520, 1414250640, 1414250760, 1414250880, 1414250940, 1414251060, 1414251240, 1414251900, 1414252020, 1414252080, 1414252200, 1414252260, 1414252380, 1414252440, 1414252440, 1414252500, 1414252560, 1414252680, 1414252980, 1414253160, 1414253460, 1414253580), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

Then I want to have a timeseq that runs for the whole period (so also the days that don't have any observations) divided by the predetermined timestep.

```
timestep = 1800 # 1800 sec = 30 min
start = "2014-10-21 00:00"
end = "2015-10-21 23:59"
receiver = R125926

timeseq = seq(from = as.POSIXct(start), to = as.POSIXct(end), by = timestep)
```

Now I want to 'fill' a new dataframe with the timeseq in one column and the count data of how many observations (from dateseq) occurred in that time period.

---

**EDIT**
After some searching on the forum and adjusting some code, I came to one very simple method that brings me very close to what I want my results to look like:

```
det_interval = data.frame(table(cut(dateseq, breaks = "30 min")))
```

There's only two adjustments that I don't know how to do. Now it begins at the first record (e.g. when my first record is on 05.17 the interval it will use will be x.17 - x.47 (30min)), not at the start that I want (see the timeseq created above). So how can I make sure that this starts and ends at a predetermined date/time?

Comment: Take a look at `?cut.Date`

Comment: Thank you, but I want the timesteps where no observations occurred to be present as zero, not completely left out..

Comment: @DavidArenburg After your answer I looked more closely to the cut function, bringing me VERY close to what I want. Edited my post to that, hope you can help me solve this smaller problem?